# How to convert this into a dictionary of a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, lambda, group-by

How do I change this to : `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, double>>`

```
var data = segGroups.Join(pPeriods, s => s.segid, p => p.entid, (s, p) => new
            {
                Name = s.SegCode, // string
                Time = p.StartLocal, // datetime
                TR = p.Volume // double
            })
            .GroupBy(s => s.Name)
            .ToList();
```

The string will be the `Name`, and the internal dictionary will be the `DateTime` and `TR` pairs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var dictionary = data.ToDictionary(group => group.Key, 
    group => group.ToDictionary(item => item.Time, item => item.TR));
```

Note that there is no *casting* going on here.  Casting is treating something as something else, without changing what it really is.  This is *converting* the list into the dictionary by creating an entirely new object that is simply based on some other value.  It's an important distinction.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call `ToList()` before `ToDictionary` unless you're really using that list somewhere else:

```
var data = segGroups.Join(pPeriods, s => s.segid, p => p.entid, (s, p) => new
                    {
                        Name = s.SegCode, // string
                        Time = p.StartLocal, // datetime
                        TR = p.Volume // double
                    })
                    .GroupBy(s => s.Name)
                    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToDictionary(i => i.Time, i => i.TR));
```

`data` will be typed into `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, double>>`.

You also have to be sure that `Time` within each group is unique. `ArgumentException` will be thrown otherwise, because two items in `Dictionary` can't have the same `Key`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the i.TR needs to be i=>i.TR